# destroy session after user is deleted but still logged in

Tags: php, session, login-script

In the login.php i check if everething is ok and if its i creat the session and redirect the user

```
 $success = $dbh->prepare("SELECT UserId FROM users WHERE username =:username 
AND password=:password");
    $success->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $success->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $success->execute();
    $rowSuccess = $success->fetch();
    $user_id = $rowSuccess['userid'];

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 1;
```

So how to destroy the user session when i delete him if he is still logged in

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you call on `session_destroy()` your `$_SESSION['user_id']` and `$_SESSION['loggedIn']` will cease to exist. So when the user refreshes the page, have an `if` condition to check for the userId and call

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['userId'])) { //if the session variable for this doesn't userId exist

   print "Sorry, no recognized account";   
 }
```

**EDIT:**

This sounds more like an AJAX solution since you wanna do some action immediately when the user is deleted. In your JavaScript set up an ajax request that calls the PHP script performing this delete action. Then, when the action is completed, alert the user and take him/her to a different page using `window.location`. To summarize

```
  $.ajax({
 url:"deleteUser.php",
 cache:false,
 success:function(data){
       alert("Sorry you have been deleted. Re-routing to home page");
               window.location="homepage.php";
       }       
});
```

Comment: I think Marian was asking what to do, when user is logged in, and he delete that user from database ;)

Comment: Then this is more of a asynchronous process. Have an AJAX request that checks for the deleted action and alerts the user that he/she was just deleted.

Comment: The ajax wont work because if i redirect him with window.location to the home page still session is not delete. In the login.php i check if the session exit because i dont want already logged in user to log in again.

Comment: I see. Leave out the AJAX request then but `session_destroy()` should help you anyway

Comment: I dont get it.. i mean let say i'm user with id=55 and i delete users with id = 76,95,443 ... and if i use session_destroy() it will destroy my session not theres,right ?

Comment: no, session_destroy() kills all the data associated with current user session on a different machine. It wouldn't kill yours at any chance.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch user data from database on every request, if user doesn't exist or is inactive you can destroy session.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) is what you may want.

Note this from the `session_destroy()` docs, though:

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.